# Can't add django.contrib.comments into Installed Apps

Tags: python, django

The problem is that whenever I put django.contrib.comments into INSTALLED APPS like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
)
```

I got this problem:

[image: Error]

Where is mistake?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.contrib.comments` depends on `django.contrib.sites` app. Change your `INSTALLED_APPS` to:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.comments',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'my_app',
)
```

FYI, see [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/comments/models.py#L5).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a dependency on django-comments and you need to add 'django.contrib.sites' to your installed apps.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't find it in the documentation directly I'm pretty sure django.contrib.comments has a dependency to django.contrib.sites which you have to add also to your INSTALLED_APPS first.

The Comments model has a foreign key to Sites, more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/models/

Note: Django’s comment framework has been deprecated.